# How to retrieve custom profile fields associated with different users

Tags: plugin-development, forms, users

I'm working on a very simple wordpress plugin that checks the database for existing users and returns specific profile fields associated with these users e.g bank account number, mobile number with some predefined texts. Can someone point me in the right direction.It will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please see [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In my opinion you should at least read: [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [get_userdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very high-level answer, but should get you in the right direction.

First, you probably need to get all of these users. You can do that with `get_users()`, which will then return an array of all users.

Next loop through that array and pass each user's ID into `get_user_meta()`, if that's where you're storing these various fields. You can either pass in a key or nothing to return all users meta associated with that user.

If you're trying to get data that's held by WP_User, you can use `get_userdata()` for each user.

I hope that helps? Most logical location to store this stuff is in user meta, in my opinion, and so `update_user_meta()` will be useful in actually saving these data to users to begin with.